# React component not re-rendering, although Object in props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I know, there are many, many similary questions.. ***duplicate alarm!***

**But:** I looked through all of them, I promise. I'm quite sure now, that this is another case, that could have to do with the props being an object (from what I've read here). But I couldn't solve the following, anyway:

```
class CsvListDropdown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { sessions: props.sessions }
        this csvsInSession = this.csvsInSession.bind(this);
    }

    csvsInSession(sessions) {
        return (sessions
            .map(keys => Object.entries(keys)[2][1])
            .map((csv, i) => (
                <option value={csv} key={i}>{csv}</option>
            ))
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading } = this.props
        if (isLoading) { blablabla.. }
        else {
            return (
                ...
                <select value={this.props.sessions[0].currentCsv}>
                    {this.csvsInSession(this.state.sessions)}
                </select>
                ...
            )
        }
    }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('sessions');
    return {
      isLoading: !handle.ready(),
      sessions: Sessions.find({}).fetch() 
    };
})(CsvListDropdown);
```

Now from the client I am writing another document into the *Sessions* collection, containing the .csv filename, while this new csv file is being uploaded to a remote server. `console.log(this.props.sessions)` gives me an array, which is up to date. But the component itself does not re-render.

What I also don't understand is: `console.log(this.state.sessions)` returns `undefined`. (note: **state**)

What I tried so far:

- `{this.csvsInSession(this.props.sessions)}` (note: **props**)
- Adding a `withTracker` / `State` / `Props` to the parent component and passing the `sessions` object from either `state` or `props` as params to the child component, that should re-render.
- forceUpdate()
- componentWillUpdate()

What may be important as well: The component should re-render about the same time another component also re-renders (which displays the contents of uploaded CSVs, that return from a microservice and get written into another collection). The latter does actually re-render.. But that dropdown does not.. argh!

Comment: Any reason you're storing sessions in state?

Comment: What does `console.log(sessions)` look like right as you enter the `csvsInSession` function?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so please mark it as accepted, or if you're still having trouble provide more info about the problem.

Comment: Ted: Yes, I thought I had to, in order to make the component re-render. Which is not the case. It re-renders as soon as the props change, correct?
@mhodges: Good question. Actually this is what I had done already, and thus didn't get why it printed the latest item in the sessions array.
So actually the Component had been updating all the time, I simply didn't notice it, because I had an error sorting the documents in the collection, and so the last entry was silently appended to the dropdown list at the bottom(!), without changing the selected value. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I finally solved it, and it turns out that the component **did** actually update at any time, but I did not **notice** it, simply because the latest item in the array was quietly appended to the **bottom** of the dropdown list. This however I was not expecting, as I had **published** the collection with a descending *sorting*.

```
// server-side
Meteor.publish('sessions', function() {
    return Sessions.find({ userId: this.userId }, { sort: {createdAt: -1} });
});
```

Server-side seems to be the wrong place to sort. It simply does not have an effect. So sorted on the client side, when subscribing:

```
// client-side
export default withTracker(() => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('sessions');
    return {
      isLoading: !handle.ready(),
      sessions: Sessions.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1} }).fetch() 
    };
})(App)
```

I had omitted an important detail from my question, that is how I set the **value** of the dropdown field:

```
<select value={this.props.sessions[0].currentCsv}>
    {this.csvsInSession(sessions)}
</select>
```

So lesson learned: If you think your react component does not re-render, always check if that's true, before assuming so.

---

As a side effect of debugging I restructered my components. Now the `Meteor.subscribe()` is within the parent component, that contains all the children, that have to handle the `sessions` object. And the `sessions` object gets passed down from the parent to the (grand)children as props. I think it's more readable and easier to maintain that way.

Answer (score 4):

`this.state` will only change if you call `this.setState()`, which you are not doing. You are initializing `state` with a value from `props`, but only in the constructor when the component is first instantiated. After that, even if `props` changes your component may re-render but what it displays won't change because `state` hasn't been updated.

In fact, there does not appear to be any reason whatsoever to store data in state in that component. It might as well be a functional presentational component:

```
function CsvListDropdown(props) {
    function csvsInSession(sessions) {
        return (sessions
            .map(keys => Object.entries(keys)[2][1])
            .map((csv, i) => (
                <option value={csv} key={i}>{csv}</option>
            ))
        )
    }

    const { isLoading } = props;
    if (isLoading) { blablabla.. }
    else {
        return (
            ...
            <select>
                {csvsInSession(props.sessions)}
            <select>
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Generally all of your components should be [stateless functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) unless they specifically need to store internal state for some reason.

Comment: Thank you @jered. I did some reading on stateless functional components, again. It was a good reminder, and I will use them where it is purely presentational, and will propably stay presentational. I want to avoid converting functional components to class components, if state is needed later.
In case of this dropdown component I need state, because I want to `Meteor.call()` *onChange* of the value of the dropdown field. Btw I  also restructured my components so that the subscription gets handled by one single parent component. `this.state !== this.setState()` <- that was helpful, indeed.